# Why tar include more file than provided?

Tags: linux, tar

I create a tar  with following command:

```
   tar -cvf demo.tar a.txt b.txt
```

When I check what's contained in demo.tar, I get:

[image]

When I try to figure out what's inside "./._a.txt", I can't find it:

[image]

My question is: what is this stuff "./._a.txt"  and how to get rid of it?

I am using bsdtar 2.8.3.

Comment: What is the output of `cat ._a.txt`? I am also using bsdtar 2.8.3, and do not see that extra file.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75989/why-does-osx-add-extra-filename-when-i-tar-a-directory might be relevant.

Comment: Just update my post for your query. @MattBall